# FileNotFoundError during importing a csv file using pandas, Jupyter notebook and Windows7

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, jupyter

I try to learn programming and currently fail to read a csv-file into a Jupyter notebook. This is what my code looks like and the response to it:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pwd

Out [2]: 'C:\\Users\\Stefan'

In [3]: cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hobby\\Geron_Geld

In [4]: pwd

Out [4]: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hobby\\Geron_Geld'

In [5]: pd.read_csv('oecd_bli_2015.csv')
```

And this is the response:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-daa5a9ab604d> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_csv('oecd_bli_2015.csv')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    438 
    439     # Create the parser.
--> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    441 
    442     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    786 
--> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    788 
    789     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1013         if engine == 'c':
-> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1015         else:
   1016             if engine == 'python':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1707 
-> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1709 
   1710         passed_names = self.names is None

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'oecd_bli_2015.csv' does not exist
```

## ============================================

- I already tried to use several parameters for pd.read_csv.
- The folder and the file exist and also the file format is correct.
- I also watched several Youtube videos about the normal procedure for this and tried all variants I found, none worked
- The following code (from another task I tried to do) works if Notepad++ is used for programming:

`training_data_file = open("C:\Program Files (x86)\Hobby\Picture recognition\mnist_train.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
training_data_file.close()`

If I use the same code in the Jupyter notebook the file will not be found again. However, I would like to practice with Jupyter notebooks/generally with programming.

It would be great if someone could please give me a hint why I can't find a way to display a csv file in a Jupyter notebook so that i can work with its data afterwards... Thank you

(My OS is Windows7)

[Image with both opened csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy37Y.jpg)

Comment: notepad++ opens `mnist_train.csv` wheras pandas opens `'oecd_bli_2015.csv'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path to the file, like this:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Hobby\Geron_Geld\oecd_bli_2015.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I use your code exactly as you wrote it I get a SyntaxError. Therefore I changed the code as follows:
pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hobby\\Geron_Geld\\oecd_bli_2015.csv')
Then I get the same FileNotFoundError as my code above. If I use the other csv file (mnist_train) everything works as it should. Therefore I thought that there might be a difference between the files, even if the image shows only data which is separated by comma...

Comment: @Burhan Khalid and I are actually giving you same answer, i'm just trying to lead there instead of tell you outright.  The reason you're getting the syntax error with his syntax is because of the `r`.  I'd look up `r` strings and do some research to proceed further with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you are actually changing the working directory the way you think you are.

try this to see what your actual directory is:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

Your working dir in python is determined by where you execute the python interpreter, it doesn't necessarily have any connection to operation shell commands like `cd`.

Check out the `os` module for everything you need to change the directory within the interpreter context.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I found the error, it seems to be the csv file. I have attached a link to an image showing the content of two csv files to the bottom of the first post. However, I wonder why one csv file can be read with the above code and the other not? Both files have commas for separation and the file which does not work has text in many entries...

I would be happy if you (or someone else) could also answer that question.

Comment: @StefanJ, please don't link to resources, post them in the question.  Linked resources can decay and thus make your post unusable by other readers.  Please refer to the rules for posting questions on stack exchange.

Comment: @StefanJ As far as  your question goes, if it was a case of an illegal file read, you wouldn't be throwing a `FileNotFoundError`.  Is that still the error your getting?

Comment: The code from my question reproduces still the FileNotFoundError (with csv-file oecd_bli_2015).

Comment: If I use the code of @Burhan Khalid I only get an SyntaxError. If I change the code to the following, I get again the same FileNotFoundError as with Method1: pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Hobby\\Geron_Geld\\oecd_bli_2015.csv') If I try this code with the other csv file (mnist_train) everything works as it should. Therefore I thought that it might be

Comment: By the way, I could only insert the picture as a link because I get a message not to be allowed to post pictures because I am a new member... Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @StefanJ this is easily troubleshot by using the `os` library.  I would look through that if I were you and try to figure out if there is something in there that can help you confirm the existence and validity of your `FullFileName`.